# Add a callback for key pressed event in QDialog without extending the class

Tags: c++, qt, callback

I have a `MainWindow` with a `QLabel` for visualize some `QPixmap`. I have subclassed the QLabel class in, let's say, MyVisualizer, for handling the QPixmap generation/modification/whatever.

Now in the MainWindow, with a key pressed I want the QLabel to fullscreen, and due to the `showFullScreen` method works only on windows, I have created a `QDialog`, moved the myvisualizer instance inside of it, and called `QDialog::showFullScreen`.Then, I'd like to have another key-pressed listener in the QDialog for some other actions.

Is it possible to add a `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)` callback to QDialog without subclassing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class KeyPressEater : public QDialog
 {
     Q_OBJECT
     ...
     KeyPressEater(Qobject paarent);
 protected:
     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
 };
 KeyPressEater::KeyPressEater(Qobject* parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
  installEventFilter(this);
}
 bool KeyPressEater::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
 {
     if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
         qDebug("Ate key press %d", keyEvent->key());
         return true;
     } else {
         // standard event processing
         return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
     }
 }
```

Comment: In main question there are text "without extending the class". Did you see it?

Comment: Did you see that i'm extending QDIalog?

Comment: Yes, you extend it by subclassing. Do you know other way to extend it?

Comment: if you are using actyaly QDialog than you can just call dilaog->installEventFilter(this); and in decalaration of this class method eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event); must exest.

Comment: Usaly QDialog is subclassed and in realisation of this class all such operations were done.

Comment: If you don't use subclassing of QDialog, then what is the difference with answer of @Greenflow?

Comment: just example with full explanation...answers are indentianal

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can install an eventFilter.

```
void QObject::installEventFilter(QObject * filterObj)
```

Comment: But remember that event filters executes before target widget events handlers (is you need them)